# Grothendieck's constant

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, approximation-hardness

I have been trying to understand the applicability of Grothendieck's constant of a graph G and hardness of approximation of combinatorial problems such as Clique $\omega(G)$, Independent Set $\alpha(G)$ and Chromatic Number $\chi(G)$. The literature seems fairly new and the relevant material is scattered.

The abstract/first section of [this paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/grothen.pdf) provides the following as definition of Grothendieck Constant:

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be a finite graph and let $a:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
>   $f_{S}:V\rightarrow S$ and $f_{\pm1}:V\rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ be
>   functions from edges to reals, vertices to the unit sphere in $|V|-1$ dimensions and
>   vertices to $\{-1,1\}$ respectively.
>
> Grothendieck's constant $K(G)$ is the smallest $K$ such that for
>   every $a$, we have:
>
> $$ \sup_{f_{S}} \sum_{\{s,t\}\in E} a(s,t)\langle f_{S}(s),f_{S}(t)\rangle\le K\sup_{f_{\pm1}} \sum_{\{s,t\}\in E}a(s,t) f_{\pm1}(s) f_{\pm1}(t) $$

- How is this constant calculated and shown explicitly related to hardness of approximation of the above three sample problems ?
- Is there a literature survey that provides details of relevance of $K(G)$ to such problems?
- Is $K(G) = 1$ when $\chi(G) = 2$ (does anyone know a proof)? (I bet I saw a reference on this but cannot locate again)

Some additions:
A survey for mathematicians is provided [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2012-49-02/S0273-0979-2011-01348-9/S0273-0979-2011-01348-9.pdf).

Comment: (1) I think that the Grothendieck constant of a graph G is usually denoted by K(G), which is different from the original version of Grothendieck’s constant (not of a graph), which is sometimes denoted by K_G.

Comment: (2) “Is K_G=1 when χ(G)=2?”  No!  The supremum of the Grothendieck constant of graph G over all bipartite graphs G is exactly the original “Grotendieck’s constant.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto For $(1)$ - that is what I implied. I will change the notation. For $(2)$ - Yes that is true. May be I am confusing $1$ with $O(1)$. However I think I am reasonably sure I saw the value quoted.

Comment: As for (2), that is what I said.  It is bounded by a constant for bipartite graphs, where the constant is of course independent of the graph, and this is the original version of the [Grothendieck inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_inequality).  Alon, Makarychev, Makarychev, and Naor ([4] in the survey), who introduced the notion of the Grothendieck constants of graphs, showed that K(G) is bounded by a function of the chromatic number of a graph which grows as O(log χ(G)).

Comment: By the way, you are still confusing “Grothendieck’s constant” (a universal constant which does not depend on graphs) and “the Grothendieck constant of a graph”.  I do not think that we say “Grothendieck’s constant of a graph.”

Comment: I do not think that this question is well-posed.  It is based on OP’s vague memory, part of which has already turned out to be imprecise.  I think that OP should check the literature more carefully.